# Change binding property path of textblock inside listbox programmatically - windows 8 app

Tags: c#, binding, windows-8, path, app-store

I need change binding property path of textblock inside listbox programmatically is there any solution? Property path should be changes depending on the current day. For example if is Monday then Text="{Binding SubjectLongNameMonday}", if is Tuesday then Text="{Binding SubjectLongNameTuesday}" etc...

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbToday" Loaded="lbToday_Loaded">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <Grid x:Name="gridTodayBtn" Tag="{Binding}" Tapped="gridTodayBtn_Tapped">

 <TextBlock x:Name="tbTodaySubjectNameMonday" Text="{Binding SubjectLongNameMonday}"/>

                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

C# code

```
 if (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString().Equals("Monday")) 
        {
            Binding myBinding2 = new Binding();
            myBinding2.Source = this;
            myBinding2.Path = new PropertyPath("MyDatasTimetableMonday");
            lbToday.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding2);
            //here need change path in xaml of textblock tbTodaySubjectNameMonday  Text="{Binding SubjectLongNameMonday}" to  Text="{Binding SubjectLongNameTuesday}"
        }
```

Comment: That's a bad idea. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? There might be better alternatives

Comment: Here is image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40039421/bindingPath.png I have binded data to listbox. When I click on row then show something. Every tap on different row show something different. Now I need depend on day change binded data ObservableCollection monday, ObservableCollection tuesday etc.

Comment: Create a property which returns appropriate collection based on the current day rather than changing the binding value

Comment: hm I m not sure how do this. Can you recommend me somesamle please. Im using now this>  private ObservableCollection<BindingData> _mydata = new ObservableCollection<BindingData>();
        public ObservableCollection<BindingData> MyDatas
        {
            get { return _mydata; }
            set { _mydata = value; }
        }

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is by SetValue:

```
lbToday.SetValue(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, this);
```